# Longest path in a Direct Acyclic Graph

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, longest-path

How can I find the longest path in a DAG with no weights?

I know that the longest path from A to B can be found in linear time if the DAG is topologically sorted, but I need to find the longest path in all the graph. Is there any way faster than searching for the longest path between all pairs of vertices( which would be O(n^3))?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same as finding the critical path.

There's an easy O(n) DP solution:

- Topologically sort the vertices.
- For each vertex `i` we will record `earliest(i)`, the earliest possible start time (initially 0 for all vertices).  Process each vertex `i` in topologically-sorted order, updating (increasing) `earliest(j)` for any successor vertex `j` of `i` whenever `earliest(i) + length(i, j) > earliest(j)`.

After this is done, the maximum value of `earliest(i)` over all vertices will be the length of the critical path (longest path).  You can construct a (there may in general be more than one) longest path by tracing backwards from this vertex, looking at its predecessors to see which of them could have produced it as a successor (i.e. which of them have `earliest(i) + length(i, j) == earliest(j)`), iterating until you hit a vertex with no predecessors.