# Path covering maximum nodes in a DAG

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I am working on a program that involves finding the longest sequence in a unweighted directed acyclic graph. I don't just need the length but also the sequence, covering the possibility of multiple sequences of the same longest length. I have tried out with DFS and Floyd-Warshall's algorithm, but have been unsuccessful so far. Could anyone give some idea as to how this question could be approached?

Thanks!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858303/longest-path-in-a-direct-acyclic-graph) answer your question? It's a topo. sort followed by a one variable dynamic program.

Comment: Not exactly...but thanks! I beat my head enough to figure out a way using DFS and points to record traversed paths and save largest ones in a 2D array(double pointer based).